# pass the value of the query too PHP from java script

Tags: php, ajax

I am building an application. The main purpose of my work is to change an object in the php page according to the database entries.

I have one php file `ajax.php`. It will query the database table and return the value to my other file main.php

The main page uses ajax to query the database. And depending on the database return it will show some images to some positions in the php page.

Example: if the return value from the database query is 2: it will show image at (x1,y1) position and it will blink, and open one small window.

If the return value from the database query is 3: it will show image at (x2,y2) position and it will blink and open one window2

I am not being able to pass the ajax query value to my php portion. Only if I want to ptint the value in  then it is possible.

But I want to do something like

if ($returnvalue == 1)

```
 window.open("window1");
 blink_image1();
```

if ($returnvalue == 2)

```
 window.open("window2");
 blink_image2();
```

Please help me.

Following are the code snippet:

ajax.php

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','database');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");

$sql='SELECT id FROM table_name order by timedate asc' ;

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $value = $row['id'];

}
echo $value;  
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

main.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:135px; LEFT:350px; WIDTH:900px;   HEIGHT:500px"SRC="testrect1.php"/>
    <script>
    var refreshtime=10000;
    function showUser(str)
    {
        setTimeout(showUser,refreshtime);
        if (str=="")
            {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                var msg=document.getElementById("txtHint");
            }

        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="showUser(this.value)">
    <div id="txtHint"></p> </div>

    <?php

/*
    I need the return value here.. So that I can do
    if ($return_val == 1)
    Blink_image1();
    open_window1();
    .

    if ($return_val == 2)
    Blink_image2();
    open_window2();
 */
    ?>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Please help me..

Comment: First try jQuery. It's easier than native JS. [Link here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
Then, did you receive something in your php files ?

Comment: Why do you have an image tag in the `<head>` tag? That doesn't go there.

Comment: first, try to learn HTML before endeavoring into ajax, PHP and MySQL... learn to walk before you run.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to pass back the AJAX request to the PHP file as the page is still loading. That will not work. PHP executes on the server, but javascript executes in the user's browser. That means you can't have javascript generated by a file send back information to the file that's generating it, because there is no way for the result to get there.

Think of it like sending a boat across a river: if you get to the other side, you may notice that you don't have a rope to tie the boat up with. However, you can't then add the rope to the boat, because it's already there with you; you need to either plan ahead ("I should really bring a rope with me") or send for another boat to bring you a rope.

What you can do instead is one of three things, in the order in which I would recommend them:

1. Since you want the information displayed at pageload anyway, you can simply put the code in the same page as you want it to appear. So in your code, where you put your comment about "here's where I need this to happen," put your database call and logic there, rather than in a separate ajax.php file.
2. Put the logic for what to display inside ajax.php, so that instead of sending the number to the browser, you're sending what it is you want to display.
3. Put the logic for what to display inside your javascript function.